# ffmpeg merge audio of two videos

Tags: audio, video, merge, ffmpeg

i have a couple of videos and i want to make them smaller to save some space... therefore i really would like to merge the audiotracks of file1 into file2
so that i can later on delete file1 because the picture content of both videos is the same...
Is there a way to accomplish that with ffmpeg? With this cmd i would have 2 video/audio tracks in one file so this is NOT what i want.

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -i file2.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

i only want the audio of file1 and the video and audio of file2 merge into one file...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the map option:

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -i file2.mp4 -map 1 -map 0:a -c copy output.mp4
```

This selects all streams from the 2nd input and the audio streams from the first.

BTW, your command wouldn't have copied both audio and video tracks; only one audio and video from among both inputs. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection

Comment: Is it also possible to only convert the audio of a mp4 file and passtrough the video content?

Comment: Yes, change `-c copy` to `-c:v copy`

Comment: You are my hero :)

Comment: And one last question. Is there a way to rename the audio track of a mp4 file?
with e.g. "Subler" i can do that but it takes quite long because its a GUI and OS X tool only